# How to make the specific dataset of the bar when clicked unchanged and remaining bars turn opaque from the respective color in chartjs

Tags: chart.js

[image]

My requirement is to click on say 1st bar and Issues section, so only that would remain unchanged, but the remaining part of the same bar and other bars turn opaque using chartjs.

Looks like chartjs does not have any api to change the background color of specific dataset of the clicked bar.

I tried the below code, but the red color does not stick. It flashes red for a second and turn to its default color.

```
onClick: (event: any, elements: any) => {
  const res = event.chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(
    event,
    'nearest',
    { intersect: true },
    true
  );
  // If didn't click on a bar, `res` will be an empty array
  if (res.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  const currentDatasetIndex = res[0].datasetIndex;
  const currentIndex = res[0].index;
  elements[currentDatasetIndex].element.options.backgroundColor = "red";
  event.chart.update(true);
 
}
```